# Update column in Oracle table with value from another table with duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to update the column (REPT_IND) from table A to the value in table B where A.ID = B.ID and some conditions in table B.
There are some duplicates in table B, but nonetheless the REPT_IND is the same and I still need the value.
How can I do this on Oracle? Any tips are appreciated thank you!

The Following code has the Error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Code:

```
UPDATE A
SET REPT_IND= (
                        SELECT B.REPT_IND
                        FROM  B
                        INNER JOIN A
                            ON B.ID = A.ID
                        where A.ID = B.ID
                        and B.job_type = 'P'
                        and B.FT_PT is not null
                        );
```

Comment: do you want to set REPT_IND to null in case if there is no rows in B satisfying you conditions?

Comment: yes @SayanMalakshinov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try also `merge` statement:

```sql
merge into a 
using (
    select a.id,max(b.rept_ind) rept_ind
    from  a left join b on a.id=b.id
    where b.job_type = 'p'
      and b.ft_pt is not null
) b
on (a.id=b.id)
when matched then update 
    set a.rept_ind=b.rept_ind;
```

Or if you do not want to set a.rept_ind to null if there is no relevant rows in b:

```sql
merge into a 
using (
    select b.id, max(b.rept_ind) rept_ind
    from  b
    where 
            b.job_type = 'p'
        and b.ft_pt is not null
    group by b.id
) b
on (a.id=b.id)
when matched then update 
    set a.rept_ind=b.rept_ind;
```

Comment: This ran without errors but it didn't update any rows

Comment: How did you check it? What does this query return: `select count(distinct b.id) c from b where b.job_type = 'p' and b.ft_pt is not null and exists(select 1 from a where a.id=b.id)`

Comment: @Anderson are you sure that you have correlated rows in B with your conditions?

Comment: I ran the above query and I got 35k rows

Comment: @Anderson ok, so merge should have been update those 35k rows. How did you check number of updated rows?

Comment: It updated the rows!! Thanks I ran the second query you provided in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use a correlated subquery . . . and do not repeat the table reference in the subquery:

```
UPDATE A
    SET REPT_IND = (SELECT B.REPT_IND
                    FROM  B
                    WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND
                          B.job_type = 'P' AND
                          B.FT_PT is not null AND
                          rownum = 1
                   );
```

Comment: That looks alot cleaner thank you.. but i still get :ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: @Anderson . . . That would seem to be a flaw in your data model -- that you have multiple matching rows.  Your choice is aggregation or adding `rownum = 1`.  I added the latter to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
update a
set rept_ind= (
    select max(b.rept_ind)
    from  b
    where 
        a.id = b.id
        and b.job_type = 'p'
        and b.ft_pt is not null
);
```

There is no need to `join` table `a` again in the subquery - a correlation clause is enough. And you can work around possible duplicates by turning on aggregation, which guarantees that only one row will be returned.

You could also use `select distinct` instead of `select max(...)` in the subquery. This is somehow more accurate since it does ensure that the multiple rows have the same `rept_ind` (it they do not, then you would still get the `ORA-01427` error).

Comment: This has been running for about 15 minutes with no errors so far, it will be updating approx 35k rows... is this normal? (I'm connected to the database perfectly fine) or could this be an issue with the query? @gmb

Comment: @Anderson: consider an index on `b(id, type, ft_pt)` to speed up the query.